# Can't boot from RAID array - arrays not assembled at boot

Tags: grub2, mdadm, raid1

On my lubuntu 13.10, I created a degraded RAID array, copied all the contents of the "main" disk and tried to boot from the array. I mostly followed [these instructions](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2013/12/01/setting-up-raid-using-mdadm-on-existing-drive/).

At boot the system does not recognize the root partition (`ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/THE-ROOT-ARRAY-ID does not exist`). I executed `blkid` from initramfs shell and raid arrays were not listed.

## UPDATE:

Also `cat /proc/mdstat` and `ls /dev/md*` gives me no result. I also tried to add the `raid1` module manually to `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`, but nothing. Raid arrays are not assembled even during normal boot: I stopped it editing the root UUID in the main menuentry from grub.

Note that if the OS starts normally, arrays are assembled. Furthermore I can assemble the arrays in the initramfs shell mounting manually the root partition and executing

`/mnt/sbin/mdadm --assemble --scan`

## OLD INFORMATIONS (probably useless):

So I checked if correct raid modules are loaded using

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all -v > ~/initout.txt
cat ~/initout.txt | grep raid
```

This is the result:

```
Adding module /lib/modules/3.11.0-13-generic/kernel/lib/raid6/raid6_pq.ko
Adding module /lib/modules/3.11.0-13-generic/kernel/drivers/scsi/raid_class.ko
Adding module /lib/modules/3.11.0-13-generic/kernel/drivers/scsi/aacraid/aacraid.ko
Adding module /lib/modules/3.11.0-13-generic/kernel/drivers/scsi/megaraid.ko
Adding module /lib/modules/3.11.0-13-generic/kernel/drivers/scsi/megaraid/megaraid_mm.ko
Adding module /lib/modules/3.11.0-13-generic/kernel/drivers/scsi/megaraid/megaraid_sas.ko
Adding module /lib/modules/3.11.0-13-generic/kernel/drivers/scsi/megaraid/megaraid_mbox.ko
Adding module /lib/modules/3.11.0-13-generic/kernel/drivers/scsi/pmcraid.ko
[...]
```

It seems that the correct raid module, `/lib/modules/3.11.0-13-generic/kernel/drivers/md/raid1.ko`, is not added. This is the content of my `/etc/mdadm.conf` file:

```
DEVICE /dev/sda* /dev/sdb*

ARRAY /dev/md/root metadata=1.2 name=root-array UUID=0e3ae751:5bca2767:a0de084c:c92033b1
ARRAY /dev/md/win  metadata=1.2 name=win-array  UUID=3c03111e:2658df20:2a8aba2d:e6ade522
ARRAY /dev/md/boot metadata=1.2 name=boot-array UUID=ab40adc4:20238d93:29ee1ab5:22608d05
ARRAY /dev/md/home metadata=1.2 name=home-array UUID=13768370:b8b8d4f4:aef53340:64626427
ARRAY /dev/md/swap metadata=1.2 name=swap-array UUID=fea8ebfd:b2c87eb2:4d8642d5:5adbb6e0
```

I also tried to move it to `/etd/mdadm/mdadm.conf` without success.

Comment: You know 13.10 reached end of life 6 months ago and is no longer supported right?  You need to upgrade.  Also `cat /proc/mdstat`.

Comment: @psusi: I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. I installed and compiled `mdadm` from source instead of installing it from repo, because of I was not sure the repo version support grub very well.

It seems that automatic inclusion of `mdadm` in initramfs is not supported by `mdadm`, but it's leaved to distro maintainers.

I manually removed it and reinstalled the repo version, all works now.